# Cannot install apk file from Eclipse Emulator to Note II

Tags: android, eclipse, installation

I am completely new to Android and Java. I am currently taking a course that is introducing me to Android and Eclipse. I am having an issue. Once I have built my app, I can run it through the virtual app, but I cannot install it to my Galaxy Note II phone. I have debugging, mock and unknown sources allowed. Eclipse can see my phone. 
Also, I am able to install the apk through explorer. I recently read that the apk should be signed as well. How do I do this and can anyone else help?

```
[2013-12-10 18:44:47 - Awesome2a] ------------------------------
[2013-12-10 18:44:47 - Awesome2a] Android Launch!
[2013-12-10 18:44:48 - Awesome2a] adb is running normally.
[2013-12-10 18:44:48 - Awesome2a] Performing myapp.awesome2a.MainActivity activity   launch
[2013-12-10 18:44:48 - Awesome2a] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
[2013-12-10 18:45:14 - Awesome2a] Uploading Awesome2a.apk onto device '42f73302b863bf67'
[2013-12-10 18:45:15 - Awesome2a] Installing Awesome2a.apk...
[2013-12-10 18:45:16 - Awesome2a] Installation failed due to invalid APK file!
[2013-12-10 18:45:16 - Awesome2a] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2013-12-10 18:45:16 - Awesome2a] Launch canceled!
```

When I take a look at Logcat, I receive this information.

```
12-10 18:44:00.002: D/STATUSBAR-Clock(3084): onReceive() - ACTION_TIME_TICK
12-10 18:44:00.007: D/STATUSBAR-Clock(3084): onReceive() - ACTION_TIME_TICK
12-10 18:44:00.032: D/ClockAlarmWidgetService(5457): [ClockAlarmWidgetService] onReceive: action = android.intent.action.TIME_TICK
12-10 18:44:00.032: E/ClockAlarmWidget(5457): [AlarmWidgetIdManager] getListItem() : itemIndex=0, widgetID:1
12-10 18:44:00.032: E/ClockAlarmWidget(5457): [AlarmWidgetIdManager] getListItem() : ItemIndex exceed ListItemCount. itemIndex=1
12-10 18:44:00.032: E/ClockAlarmWidget(5457): [AlarmWidgetIdManager] getListItem() : itemIndex=1, widgetID:1
12-10 18:44:00.032: D/ClockAlarmWidget(5457): [ClockAlarmWidgetProvider] fillData() - itemIndex:0, listitemID: 0
12-10 18:44:00.037: D/ClockAlarmDataProvider(5457): getAlarm() - too many same ID alarm data. nCount: 0
12-10 18:44:00.042: D/ClockAlarmWidget(5457): alarmItem = null
12-10 18:44:00.042: D/ClockWidget(2408): refreshTime()
12-10 18:44:00.047: D/ClockWidget(2408): TTS Message = It is 6 : 44 PM, Tuesday, December 10
12-10 18:44:05.727: E/MtpService(3505): In MTPAPP onReceive:android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
12-10 18:44:05.727: E/MtpService(3505): battPlugged Type : 2
12-10 18:44:05.727: D/BatteryService(2408): update start
12-10 18:44:05.727: D/BatteryService(2408): level:100 scale:100 status:2 health:2 present:true voltage: 4326 temperature: 249 technology: Li-ion AC powered:false USB powered:true icon:17303211 invalid charger:0
12-10 18:44:05.727: D/STATUSBAR-BatteryController(3084): onReceive() - ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED
12-10 18:44:05.727: D/STATUSBAR-BatteryController(3084): onReceive() - level:100
12-10 18:44:05.727: D/STATUSBAR-BatteryController(3084): onReceive() - plugged:2
12-10 18:44:05.727: D/STATUSBAR-BatteryController(3084): onReceive() - BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING:
12-10 18:44:05.732: D/STATUSBAR-PhoneStatusBar(3084): ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED
12-10 18:44:05.732: D/STATUSBAR-PhoneStatusBar(3084): NORMAL_BATTERY
12-10 18:44:05.737: W/AlarmManager(2408): FACTORY_ON= 0
12-10 18:44:23.687: E/Watchdog(2408): !@Sync 28
12-10 18:44:29.682: E/WifiHW(2408): ##################### set firmware type 0 #####################
12-10 18:44:29.682: D/WifiStateMachine(2408): setWifiEnabled : WifiNative.setFwType(0)
12-10 18:44:29.682: V/AlarmManager(2408): waitForAlarm result :4
12-10 18:44:29.682: V/AlarmManager(2408): trigger ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP or RTC_WAKEUP
12-10 18:44:29.682: D/WifiService(2408): startScan: false pid=3965, uid=10019
12-10 18:44:29.687: W/AlarmManager(2408): FACTORY_ON= 0
12-10 18:44:29.697: I/wpa_supplicant(3889): Scan requested (ret=0) - scan timeout 30 seconds
12-10 18:44:29.762: W/AlarmManager(2408): FACTORY_ON= 0
12-10 18:44:33.347: I/wpa_supplicant(3889): nl80211: Received scan results (9 BSSes)
12-10 18:44:33.347: D/Tethering(2408): interfaceLinkStateChanged wlan0, true
12-10 18:44:33.347: D/Tethering(2408): interfaceStatusChanged wlan0, true
12-10 18:44:33.357: W/AlarmManager(2408): FACTORY_ON= 0
12-10 18:44:33.377: D/dalvikvm(3965): GC_CONCURRENT freed 511K, 8% free 13209K/14343K, paused 1ms+1ms, total 14ms
12-10 18:44:33.377: D/dalvikvm(3965): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 8ms
12-10 18:44:33.382: W/AlarmManager(2408): FACTORY_ON= 0
12-10 18:44:33.412: E/WifiHW(2408): ##################### set firmware type 0 #####################
12-10 18:44:33.412: D/WifiStateMachine(2408): setWifiEnabled : WifiNative.setFwType(0)
12-10 18:44:33.417: W/AlarmManager(2408): FACTORY_ON= 0
12-10 18:44:33.467: I/GCoreUlr(3965): Successfully inserted location
12-10 18:44:33.467: I/GCoreUlr(3965): Not calling LocationReportingService, hasMoved: false, elapsed millis: 780030, request: Phone
12-10 18:44:34.682: V/AlarmManager(2408): waitForAlarm result :4
12-10 18:44:41.742: D/BatteryService(2408): update start
12-10 18:44:41.747: E/MtpService(3505): In MTPAPP onReceive:android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
12-10 18:44:41.747: E/MtpService(3505): battPlugged Type : 2
12-10 18:44:41.747: D/BatteryService(2408): level:100 scale:100 status:2 health:2 present:true voltage: 4326 temperature: 242 technology: Li-ion AC powered:false USB powered:true icon:17303211 invalid charger:0
12-10 18:44:41.747: D/STATUSBAR-BatteryController(3084): onReceive() - ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED
12-10 18:44:41.747: D/STATUSBAR-BatteryController(3084): onReceive() - level:100
12-10 18:44:41.747: D/STATUSBAR-BatteryController(3084): onReceive() - plugged:2
12-10 18:44:41.747: D/STATUSBAR-BatteryController(3084): onReceive() - BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING:
12-10 18:44:41.762: W/AlarmManager(2408): FACTORY_ON= 0
12-10 18:44:41.762: D/STATUSBAR-PhoneStatusBar(3084): ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED
12-10 18:44:41.762: D/STATUSBAR-PhoneStatusBar(3084): NORMAL_BATTERY
12-10 18:44:41.777: D/dalvikvm(3965): GC_CONCURRENT freed 396K, 8% free 13201K/14343K, paused 12ms+1ms, total 27ms
12-10 18:44:53.687: E/Watchdog(2408): !@Sync 29
12-10 18:44:59.997: V/AlarmManager(2408): waitForAlarm result :8
12-10 18:44:59.997: V/AlarmManager(2408): ClockReceiver onReceive() ACTION_TIME_TICK
12-10 18:44:59.997: W/AlarmManager(2408): FACTORY_ON= 0
```

I have absolutely no clue. Can you help.

Comment: Can you install any of the demo apps, or does it give you this error with everything?

Comment: the logcat has nothing to do with the app. You yould set session filter to current pagackage. anyways, in this case i guess it wont say anything.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I would suspect that there is something wrong with the project settings or androidmanifest.xml file. In Eclipse's top bar, can you go to Run > Run Configurations, flip over to the "Target" tab and select "Always prompt to pick device" for your current configuration? Just to make sure it's being deployed to the right device. Presuming that doesn't fix it, could you post the android manifest? Also, are you using any libraries or do you have any external dependencies?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="myapp.awesome2a"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0" >                                 <uses-sdk
      android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

Comment: <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="myapp.awesome2a.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

Answer (score 0):

Usualy if you go to

```
Project > Unset build automatically
```

and then,

```
Proyect > clean
```

and then, in project explorer:

```
right click on project name > refresh
```

and then,

```
Proyect > build project
```

Then uninstall from the device any version of the app that you could have, and try to install it again.

Comment: Carlos, I tried your way and I am still getting the same result. on the last command line posted, I have the option of Build All, Build Project,Build Working set and Build Automatically. Which should I chose?

Comment: Sorry i told you by heart and didn't write the comple word, the option is build project. Build all will also be good. if you selected any other and that didnt work, you need to go further. Do you have any referenced library that is also in your workspace? If so :Try to clear  whole workspace from menu project > clear and selecting all, refresh the involved projects, and select project build all

Comment: Also, before you install it, uninstall from your device any version of the app that you could have